# How to Increase twitter web rest api endpoints limit for followers

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, rate-limiting, twitterapi-python

I am using the Twitter web API to scrape some followers. Previously, I was able to obtain around 50,000 followers in a 15-minute window, but now I am only getting 5,000 in that same time frame, and I'm hitting the rate limit 429.

`https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/xjJ7_nvN1nSB_z0VsPT0Q/Followers?`

I tried using IP proxy switching, but it seems they are checking a token that I am sending, so the backend logic is in control of this. Is there any legitimate way to avoid this limit?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are experiencing rate limiting issues. One solution could be to add a `time.sleep('number here')` function to make your program wait between each request, which should help to alleviate the problem.